# Android studio - if app build variant configuration is release do i need to change variants for other modules

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

A long title i know. Really what i am wondering is -  take a look at this image:
[image]

So i am setting the app module to a paidRelease configuration but do i need to change the wearable app i have to release ? im also using a 3rd party sliderpreference library and it set to debug per the image, do i need to change that to release when i create a production build ?

What i am currently doing now is only changing the app module to release configuration per the image and everything else i just leave in debug since i am building out jus the app module when i release i was assuming it would take the rest as production builds, can anyone confirm ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide) i read the following:

> By default a library only publishes its release variant.